# Как добавить кастомную клетку таблицы в iText?

Tags: java, itext

**Как в iText можно:**

- создать ячейку с изображением
- задать выравниваение для конкретной ячейки
- объединить несколько ячеек по горизонтали

Мне нужно чтобы каждая клетка выглядяла так, кто сможет помочь?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Баркод это картинка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у нас тут имеется таблица с двумя колонками, тремя строками и 4 ячейками, две из которых совмещены по горизонтали.

Какие могут возникнуть вопросы?

#### Как объединять ячейки

Для этого в ячейке имеется метод `setColspan(2)` в котором нужно указать, сколько колонок нужно объединить(в данном случае две)

```
barcodeCell.setColspan(2);
```

*Для объединения ячеек по вертикале сеть метод `setRowspan()`*

#### Как выравнивать контент

Для этого в параграфе есть метод `setAlignment()`, в который можно передать константу из класса `Element`, отвечающую за выравнивание по одной из сторон

```
priceCaption.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
```

#### Как вставить картинку

Для этого в ячейку нужно передать экземпляр объекта `com.itextpdf.text.Image`.
Его можно получить из локального файла следующим образом:

```
Image.getInstance("/home/michaeldl/projects/stackoverflow/barcode.png")
```

---

С основными вопросами разобрались

## К делу

#### Документ

- Создаем документ,
- получаем экземпляр PdfWriter, которому передаем OutputStream для записи файла
- и открываем данный документ для дальнейшей работы с ним

```
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("stackoverflow_example.pdf")));
document.open();
```

#### Таблица

Создаем таблицу и передаем в конструктор количество колонок (в данном случае 2)

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
```

#### Ячейка с штрихкодом

- Создаем ячейку со штрихкодом
- Объединяем ее со следующей ячейкой по горизонтали
- Добавляем в ячейку изображение штрихкода полученное из файла, лежащего на диске
- Добавляем ячейку в таблицу

```
PdfPCell barcodeCell = new PdfPCell();
barcodeCell.setColspan(2);
barcodeCell.addElement(Image.getInstance("/home/michaeldl/projects/stackoverflow/barcode.png"));
table.addCell(barcodeCell);
```

#### Ячейка с артикулом

Когда нам просто нужно создать дефолтную ячейку с текстом, без каких-либо дополнительных действий можно прокинуть содержимое ячейки непосредственно в `addCell()`

```
table.addCell(Paragraph.getInstance("0223456"));
```

#### Ячейка с ценой

- Создаем ячейку
- Создаем надпись с текстом, содержащим цену
- Устанавливаем выравнивание по правому краю
- Вставляем надпись в ячейку
- Вставляем ячейку в таблицу

```
PdfPCell priceCell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph priceCaption = new Paragraph("50,00 €");
priceCaption.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
priceCell.addElement(priceCaption);
table.addCell(priceCell);
```

#### Ячейка с названием товара

- Создаем ячейку
- Создаем надпись с текстом, содержащим название товара
- Устанавливаем выравнивание по центру
- Объединяем ее со следующей ячейкой по горизонтали
- Вставляем надпись в ячейку
- Вставляем ячейку в таблицу

```
PdfPCell nameCell = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph nameCaption = new Paragraph("+41 Eyewear +41 Eyewear Occhiale Vista Premontato Mix Vista");
nameCaption.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
nameCell.addElement(nameCaption);
nameCell.setColspan(2);
table.addCell(nameCell);
```

#### Финиш

- Добавляем таблицу в документ
- Закрываем документ

```
document.add(table);
document.close();
```

---

## Итого

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        // Создаем документ
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get("stackoverflow_example.pdf")));
        document.open();
        // Создаем таблицу
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);

        // Ячейка со штрихкодом
        PdfPCell barcodeCell = new PdfPCell();
        barcodeCell.setColspan(2);
        barcodeCell.addElement(Image.getInstance("/home/michaeldl/projects/stackoverflow/barcode.png"));
        table.addCell(barcodeCell);

        // Ячейка со артикулом
        table.addCell(Paragraph.getInstance("0223456"));

        // Ячейка с ценой
        PdfPCell priceCell = new PdfPCell();
        Paragraph priceCaption = new Paragraph("50,00 €");
        priceCaption.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        priceCell.addElement(priceCaption);
        table.addCell(priceCell);

        // Ячейка с названием
        PdfPCell nameCell = new PdfPCell();
        Paragraph nameCaption = new Paragraph("+41 Eyewear +41 Eyewear Occhiale Vista Premontato Mix Vista");
        nameCaption.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        nameCell.addElement(nameCaption);
        nameCell.setColspan(2);
        table.addCell(nameCell);

        // добавляем таблицу и закрываем документ
        document.add(table);
        document.close();
    }
}
```

---

## Результат

https://disk.yandex.ru/i/HGAInQ-zQLz9ag

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]